# Minimum of $P=\frac{a}{a+bc}+\sqrt{3}(\frac{b}{b+ca}+\frac{c}{c+ab})$ subject to $a,b,c>0: ab+bc+ca=abc$.

Tags: inequality

> Let $a,b,c>0: ab+bc+ca=abc$. Find the minimum of $$P=\frac{a}{a+bc}+\sqrt{3}\left(\frac{b}{b+ca}+\frac{c}{c+ab}\right)$$ subject to those constraints.

Let  $x=\frac{2a}{b+c}$. Then, I get
\begin{align}
P&=\frac{a^2}{(a+b)(a+c)}+\sqrt{3}\left(\frac{b^2}{(b+c)(b+a)}+\frac{c^2}{(c+a)(c+b)}\right) \\
&\ge \left(\frac{2a}{2a+b+c}\right)^2+\sqrt{3}\left(\frac{b+c}{2a+b+c}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^2+\sqrt{3}\left(\frac{1}{x+1}  \right)\,.
\end{align}
but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Then you find the minimum of $\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^2+\sqrt{3}\left(\frac{1}{x+1}  \right)$, and check that it is the minimum of $P$ as well.

Comment: What's the context where you encountered this inequality?  What's the motivation?  Can you credit the original source?  Why is this inequality relevant and useful to future users of this site?  You have listed the task in a quote block.  Please credit the original source of the quoted material: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 1):

You can change like this
$$\frac{x}{x + 1} = 1 - \frac{1}{x + 1}$$

$$\frac{1}{x + 1} = t !$$

then we can change
$$(1 - t) ^ 2 + \sqrt{3}t = (t - \frac{2 - \sqrt{3}}{2}) ^ 2 + \sqrt{3} - \frac{3}{4}$$
so the minimum of **P** is $$\sqrt{3} - \frac{3}{4}$$